# Multiple commands in deployment yaml of Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

CMD and ENTRYPOINT of my Dockerfile is overridden by commands and arg of deployment.yaml.

DockerFile snippet -

```
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["-m", "swagger_server"]
```

deployment.yaml snippet -

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "while true; do python3 -m swagger_server; echo Done Deploying sv-premier; sleep 3600;done"]
```

But its not executing. also tried multiple combinations on this pretext.

Deployment File --

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sv-premier
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sv-premier
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sv-premier
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: google-cloud-key
        secret:
          secretName: gcp-key
      containers:
      - name: sv-premierleague
        image: gcr.io/proto/premiercore1:latest
        tty: true
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do sleep 3600;done"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: google-cloud-key
          mountPath: /var/secrets/google
        env:
        - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          value: /var/secrets/google/key.json
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: imagepullsecretkey
```

Comment: What are the errors that you encounter? Can you post the full `deployment.yaml` file?

Comment: No error as such. just the commands are not being executed. 

deployment.yaml -- posted above

Comment: kubectl exec into the container and try running the command yourself form inside the container.

Comment: did.. getting error as -- OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('0.0.0.0', 5000)

But havent used this port  anywhere..i am exposing 8080..

Comment: check the process which is bound to the port. And also try a different port.

Comment: Have you tried not providing any `command` and `args` in deployment `YAML` as it's already have an `entrypoint` in docker image?

Comment: @DawidKruk - I tried without command and args but in that case I was getting CrashLoopBackOff error. So it was need to put my  container to sleep after deployment and every hour it will log the message. Thus the command and args.

Comment: @Shwet  About that `CrashLoopBackOff` .Do you know what the corresponding error was? Is the image in your `YAML` created by you? Have you tried to run it in plain Docker?